# Search form not responsive

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have created a simple search form and I am using twitter bootstrap 'latest version'. When I am viewing on a mobile device the table is responsive but the search form is not.

```
<div class"search">
 <form id="search" name ="search" method="get" action="">
   <p class="indent"><label for="artist">Search for Band:</label>
     <input name="artist" type="text" id="artist">
     <input type="submit" name="submit">
     <a href="gigs.php?artist=&submit=Submit+Query">Show all gigs</a>
   </p>
 </form>
</div>
```

If someone could point out the problem is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some extra information, like what are the css attributes for the class `search`

Comment: there is no css for that class

Comment: link some code or add a fiddle then if possible, it's kinda hard to guide you with only this information

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this should be `<div class="search">` , not `<div class"search">`

Secondly, if that doesn't fix your problem, then try something like below. Adjust according to your needs.

```
<div class="search" style="width: 50%; max-width: 300px; min-width: 140px;">
```